# Clickable jface AutoCompleteField

Tags: java, jface

Sorry in advance, English is not my native language.

In order to have auto complete activated on a `ComboBoxCellEditor` , I use an `AutoCompleteField` as such:
`new AutoCompleteField(comboBoxCellEditor.getControl(), new CComboContentAdapter(),values);`

This works well except for one thing, the suggestion given by the field are not clickable. What am I missing?

I tried to see if there is a listener or to make a Custom AutoCompleteField but to no avail.

Thank you in advance for your help!